# jQuery AJAX not working in Model View Control with htaccess

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, cross-domain

im currently working with jQuery ajax and i get some unexpected error.
I use firebug to debug javascript.
In my console the GET request link is red.

My jQuery isn't realy hard...

```
$.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: '/scores/update/' + $(this).val(), <-- could be '/scores/update/1'
    success: function( msg ) {
        $('.feedback').html( msg ).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

The map scores/update dont realy exists. I use htacces make the link into. index.php?uri=scores/update/1. After this $_GET['uri'] is going in my router.php and this will be direct to the following method

```
class scores()
{

   public function update($int)
   {

       echo $int;

   }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?
The echo wont be send, the link in my firebug console is red. Is this a cross-domain error? Is it my htaccess? It is driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's red? Does it provide an error message of any sort?

Comment: Why are you trying to echo from your controller?  Send your message back through the AJAX request and display it from your jQuery code.  The echo in the controller may fire but it will never be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the fix, In any case thanks guys.

The fix:

I had

`<input type="submit" name="score" value="1" class="score button1" />`

and jquery want me to have

`<input type="button" name="score" value="1" class="score button1" />`